# Draggable and clickable button

Tags: wpf, button, draggable

I'm trying to make button.
If user clicked/taped on it then click event fires.
If user pressed and hold and moved then drag window.

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="grid" PreviewMouseMove="Grid_PreviewMouseMove">
            <Button Content="Button" Width="100" Height="50" 
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="logListBox" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Point _startMousePosition;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            logListBox.Items.Add("Left button event.");

            _startMousePosition = e.GetPosition(grid);
        }

        private void Grid_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentMousePosition = e.GetPosition(grid);
            var isMouseMoving = _startMousePosition.X != currentMousePosition.X ||
                _startMousePosition.Y != currentMousePosition.Y;

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && isMouseMoving)
            {
                DragMove();
                logListBox.Items.Add("Drag window.");
            }
        }
    }
```

But left button event fires in case of dragging (press and hold) and in case of single click (press and release).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX4wb.png)

How can i separate it?
How is it implemented usually?

Comment: Usually? People click a button and it fires a command. Usually you would not choose to drag drop based on clicking a button. Button click already has a meaning.

Comment: @Andy But in mobile apps you could tap (left button in my case) once or tap and hold and drag (left button and move). Without double tap.